# Bone heat weighting failed to find solution!

Tags: mesh, armature, bones, weight-painting, parent

I keep getting the "Bone heat weighting failed to find solution"-error when I try to parent a mesh to an armature.

I've deleted doubles, fixed normals, added and removed various modifiers. I'm pretty sure it's because the mesh is asymmetrical, but that's on purpose and it needs to be this way.

I've also tried all Parenting options; the only one that gives the error message is "With Automatic Weights", but the rest just deform the mesh (bones only move parts of the mesh and weight paint doesn't seem to be an option).

Is there some way to get around this?could anyone please link to a way to parent an asymmetrical mesh to an armature?

PLEASE HELP I´M DESPERATE!!

Comment: Can you link your file? Could help a lot

Comment: I can't post .blend files for copyright reasons :(

Comment: mmmmm it's diffciult to understand without any file. Can i download it from any site?

Comment: sorry but it´s not possible :(

Comment: Ok i'll try to answer as generally as i can :) tell me if could help

Comment: The Automatic weight feature doesn't always work.... especially on detailed meshes (Like a character with a complex belt or complex hat), sometimes you just have to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

Follow this instruction

1. Have your mesh/armature as two objects (not parented and with no vertex groups on mesh)
2. Select mesh (object mode). Separate > Loose Parts.
3. Shift-select Armature (do shift-LMB in Outliner if you keep selecting mesh by accident).
4. Parent > Automatic Weights. This gives your meshes vertex groups.
5. Outliner - click "white arrow" of Armature to Restrict Viewport Selection.
6. (Important!) Select any obect that isn't Armature (so its name in Outliner is no longer highlighted white).
7. Select all. Join.
8. Outliner - Unrestrict viewport selection of Armature.

Tell me if it works ;)

Or try with this link

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?130935-Bone-heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones

Comment: thanks for your help but it´s still saying bone heat weighting failed to... :(

Comment: i edit with another link

Comment: thanks but i,ve tried everithing possible.Maybe the problem is that it´s nott possible to use automatic weight with an assymetrical mesh.I really appreciated your effort!! :)

Comment: Have you tired:  crtl + p and then "with empty groups"? It doesn't give the weight paint but generates vertex groups at least. Then you have to assign your bones to vertex gorups

Comment: Thanks for your help Fuboski,I finally achieved it by remodelling the mesh again.Now automatic weighting works perfectly.Thanks a lot.

Comment: GREAT MAN!! I'm glad to know it ;)